# sails.js Is it possible to set process.env variables from application?

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I am trying to use `npm` module fb to use facebook api. The config file is located in the module and here is the snapshot of the same

```
var config = { };

// should end in /
config.rootUrl  = process.env.ROOT_URL                  || 'http://localhost:3000/';


config.facebook = {
    appId:          process.env.FACEBOOK_APPID          || '130243393813697',
    appSecret:      process.env.FACEBOOK_APPSECRET      || 'c82696768ae4ad8b63db874cb64eb558',
    appNamespace:   process.env.FACEBOOK_APPNAMESPACE   || 'nodescrumptious',
    redirectUri:    process.env.FACEBOOK_REDIRECTURI    ||  config.rootUrl + 'login/callback'
};

module.exports = config;
```

I don't wish to change the config file of the module since `node_modules` folder is kept in the `gitignore` list. For configuring the module to use my app's `appId` and `appSecret`, I need to set the `process.env` variables `FACEBOOK_APPID` and `FACEBOOK_APPSECRET`

I understand that it can be done while calling the sails lift but is it by any means possible to set these values inside the app so that I only have to call

sails lift

without any of those variables and those should be set automatically ? Or what is the best way to achieve what I am trying to do here ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should set the environment-variables outside of your App.

Instead of `sails lift` you could also use `node app.js`. With that you can define environment-variables for your node-application with:

`$> FOO='bar' node app.js`

In your case:

`$> FACEBOOK_APPID='232322a22' FACEBOOK_APPSECRET='mysecrete' node app.js`

If you want to set this vars in your app (I wouldn't suggest that!) you could set them before including your npm-module. For example in your `config/bootstrap.js`:

```
module.exports.bootstrap = function(cb) {

  process.env.FACEBOOK_APPID = "myvar";
  process.env.FACEBOOK_APPSECRET = "mysecrete";
  sails.facebook = require("yourmodule");

  cb();
};
```

Comment: That's what I am currently doing but this seems error prone to me just in case someone forgets to pass these parameters while launching the app. If it is something I am going to always use when I lift the server, what would be the best way to achieve it ?

Comment: As the name said, this vars should set outside of your app- but I edited my solution for you to set them into your sails-app.

Answer (score 4):

[Here](https://noahbass.com/posts/sails-environment-config-vars) is a good link for setting environment variables when "Production", "Staging" and "Development" in Sails feels fragmented.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zDup0I2VGmk) is a quick video tutorial which simply explains how to create environment variables in node.js

**Step1:**
Install the package dotenv as dependency

```
$ npm install dotenv --save
```

**Step2:**
Then require dotenv in app.js and load the .env file

```
var dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.load();
```

**Step3:**
Create a .env file in the root folder (ie. at the same document level as app.js file)

**Step4:**
Add your environment variables

```
S3_KEY=enfiownqefniqofewqofnieqwvewlk
S3_SECRET=123456789
```

Now you can access those environment variables anywhere in the app (probably in some config/ files):

```
return {
  key: process.env.S3_KEY,
  secret: process.env.S3_SECRET,
  region: 's3-eu-west-1',
  bucket: 'myBucket',
  s3params: {
    ACL: 'public-read'
  }
}
```

Credit goes to [Noah Bass](https://noahbass.com) for providing this tutorial.

Comment: There is one problem with this approach: when using `sails generate`, or any other `sails command`, the 'app.js' file is not required, thus the env variables are not included.

Comment: There is another problem.`TypeError: dotenv.load is not a function`. To fix that - just add at the beginning of app.js `require('dotenv').config();` instead of what @Eli Peters recommended

Answer (score 0):

SailsJS has a way to set them in the environment that overrides any configs in the config files (production.js for example).

The link to the doc for this use is here:
https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/configuration#?setting-sailsconfig-values-directly-using-environment-variables

You can set the env variables like so if using the sails console (this is from the docs)

```
sails_security__cors__allowOrigins='["http://somedomain.com","https://anotherdomain.com:1337"]' sails console
```

If you are using a cloud environment, you can set it within the environment.

For setting within the app itself, use the config files structure config/env/* where *  is staging.js production.js

Make your request like so

```js
module.exports.getAccessToken = async () => {
  const tokenData = await axios({
    method: "POST",
    url: `${sails.config.custom.externalAPI.auth}`,
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    data: {
      grant_type: "client_credentials",
      client_id: `...`,
      client_secret: `...`,
      audience: ...``,
    },
  })
```

Do not use dotenv of process.env to set as sails provides you a way to do this within the framework.